# How to align external element to middle of List View Item in XAML?

Tags: xaml, windows-8

I want to do something like this -

[image]

The middle of the callout should align with middle of List View Item. How to find the actual coordinates of middle of the List View Item so that I can align the callout which is nothing but a Path element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to do something like this:

Create handler for ListView's selection changed event. In that handle put following code:

```
// step 1. Get selected item's container (ListViewItem in case of ListView)
var dependencyObject = listView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(listView.SelectedIndex);
var listViewItem = dependencyObject as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewItem;

// step 2. transform items rectangle into coordinates of containing control
var transform = listViewItem.TransformToVisual(parentContainer);
var rect = transform.TransformBounds(new Rect(0, 0, itemsControl.ActualWidth, itemsControl.ActualHeight));
var center = (rect.Top + rect.Bottom) / 2;

// step 3. position callout using center value calculated above
// exact code depends on you container, ie. Grid, Canvas, etc.
```